# PHP PDO prepared insert - does not insert data and show no errors

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo

This problem is driving me crazy, i tried everything. Is does not give me any error, but it does not insert anything to the database either. Database connection is good, and there should be no typos. Please take a look, and see if you can find the problem:

```
$err = array();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $ip = gethostbyname($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $date = "2012-02-02 02:02:02"; //Example
    $uploader_name = $_POST['uploader_name'];

    // Validation happens here...


    if (empty($err)) {

        $host = "host";
        $dbname = "db";
        $user = "user";
        $pass = "pass";

        try {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);  

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`ip`, `date`, `uploader_name`) 
                    VALUES (:ip, :date, :uploader_name)";
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

            # the data we want to insert  
            $params = array(
                ':ip' => $ip,
                ':date' => $date,
                ':uploader_name' => $uploader_name
            );


            $stmt->execute($params);

            $dbh = null;

        } catch(PDOException $pe) {
            die('SQL Error');
        }


        if (empty($err)) {
            $err[] = "Success!";
        }   
    }

}
```

Also, Im sure it gets to the insert part, because i get the 'Success' message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this code to execute your statement. If there is a non-fatal error, it will display it.

```
$stmt->execute($params) or die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true));
```

Almost certainly your db user does not have permissions to execute the statement you're asking against the table you're trying to execute against.

Comment: Thank you!! the problem was that some of the values was NULL. But its only some of the fields that is "required", how do i insert blank values to these fields?

Comment: You'd have to provide validation code for each input that you're adding to the prepared statement. if ($myVar === nulll) { $myVar = '';} or something.

Comment: 2 years later you da bomb

Answer (score 2):

Are you using auto-commit? If not you may need to wrap your query in a transaction.

```
try
{
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    // your code.
    $dbh->commit();
}
catch(PDOException $pe)
{
    $dbh->rollback();
    die($pe->getMessage());
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php